# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed when moving data between vectors

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, kalman-filter

I'm using the Kalman filter for some image tracking and at times I need to reorder data to ensure that the the indexes of different vectors are the same. I do this with a quick logic check ensuring the position from the current frame is within a tolerance against the last frame. if this is the case I move the data to a second vector to match the new index then later move the fully reordered vector back to the original vector.  As below:

```
void vector_order(vector<Rect> found_filtered)
{
    int j, i;   
    vector<KalmanFilter> organise_KF(10);
    vector<kal_ret> organise_kal(10);
    vector<FilterHistory> organise_MAV(10);
    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<track_ret.size(); j++)  //compare tracks for kalman filter
        {
            if (found_filtered[i].x >= track_ret[j].measPt.x-12 || found_filtered[i].x <= track_ret[j].measPt.x+12 )
            {
                if (found_filtered[i].y >= track_ret[j].measPt.y-30 || found_filtered[i].y <= track_ret[j].measPt.y+30 )
                {
                    organise_kal[i] = track_ret[j];
                    organise_KF[i] = KF[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//if there is no match that index will stay empty to be filled by the filter return 

        for (j=0; j<filter_ret.size(); j++)  //compare tracks for moving average filter
        {
            if (found_filtered[i].x >= filter_ret[j].current.x-12 || found_filtered[i].x <= filter_ret[j].current.x+12 )
            {
                if (found_filtered[i].y >= filter_ret[j].current.y-30 || found_filtered[i].y <= filter_ret[j].current.y+30 )
                {
                    organise_MAV[i] = filter_ret[j];
                }
            }//if there is no match that index will stay empty to be filled by the filter return
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        track_ret[i] = organise_kal[i];
        filter_ret[i] = organise_MAV[i];
        KF[i] = organise_KF[i];
    }
}
```

The problem being as soon as the system goes to use the data for a second time it throws the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)(size.p[0])*size.p[1]) && elemSize() == (((((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) << ((((sizeof(size_t)/4+1)*16384|0x3a50) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*2) & 3 ))) in unknown function, file C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 569
```

I'm new to coding. Is there a better way to reorder the data or have I just missed a simple step?

Comment: I realised the problem.  I wasn’t initialising the Kalman filters in the new vector so when the system went to use a fresh filter there was no matrix data or scaling set.  All is now much better.  Thank you for looking

Answer (score 0):

I realised the problem.  I wasn’t initialising the Kalman filters in the new vector so when the system went to use a fresh filter there was no matrix data or scaling set.  All is now much better.  Thank you for looking